# Data assigned to ViewController is null just after push?

Tags: ios, core-data, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I can't figure out why the data I'm assigning to a view controller just before pushing it is becoming null just after the push.

I'm using Core Data for storage. The `Project` object is an NSManagedObject.

This is my flow:

1. In my home view controller, I launch a UIImagePickerViewController
2. In `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` I write it a file and save the path in a core data object.
3. I grab the parent object from core data and verify that it's not null.
4. I dismiss the image picker view controller.
5. I instantiate another view controller and assign the parent object to a property on that view controller `@property (nonatomic, strong) Project * project;`.
6. I push that new view controller
7. In the view controller's `viewDidLoad` method, the object is now null.

Any idea as to why this is happening?

Here's the code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // Access the uncropped image from info dictionary
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    ImageInfo * imgInfo = [[DataController sharedController] newImageInfo];

    // Create path to output images
    NSString  *imagePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Documents/%@.%@"
                                                                                                       , imgInfo.filename
                                                                                                       , imgInfo.extension]];
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image , 0.5) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
    imgInfo.path = imagePath;

    AnnotationDocument * annDoc = [[DataController sharedController] newAnnotationDocument];
    [[DataController sharedController] associateImageInfo:imgInfo withAnnotationDocument:annDoc];

    Project * untitledProject = [[DataController sharedController] untitledProject];
    [[DataController sharedController] associateAnnotationDocument:annDoc withProject:untitledProject];
    NSLog( @"UP key: %@" , untitledProject.key );

    [[DataController sharedController] saveContext];
    NSLog( @"UP key: %@" , untitledProject.key );

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    AnnotationDocListViewController * vc = [[AnnotationDocListViewController alloc] init];
    vc.project = [[DataController sharedController] projectForKey:untitledProject.key];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: is project a weak property in AnnotationDocListViewController ?

Comment: are you sure **vc.project** is not nil?

Comment: What is `[[DataController sharedController] projectForKey:untitledProject.key]`? Maybe it is nil. You didn't log it, so how do you know?

Comment: @ThilinaHewagama Project is a strong property. I've also tried it with 'retain' (which shouldn't matter because I'm using ARC), and in fact, the same result.

Comment: You are on to something @MariamN. and @matt. vc.project was turning out to be nil. I added more logging and changed `[[DataController sharedController] projectForKey:untitledProject.key]` to just the `untitledProject` object, and vc.project is no longer nil, but `untitledProject.key` AND `vc.project.key` are BOTH nil at that point. I have no idea why `untitledProject.key` is suddenly nil.